# Regular expression to check all same 10 digit number

Tags: regex

I am using below regular expression to check 10 digit phone number with hyphen.

```
var emailformat="^((([0-9]{3}))|[0-9]{3})[s-]?[\0-9]{3}[s-]?[0-9]{4}$"
```

but i want to check user cannot enter all 10 digit same number

```
e.g: 222-222-2222 throw invalid format
e.g: 489-395-8888 valid format
```

**Please suggest regular expression to invalidate same 10 digit number?**

Comment: Please do not tag spam.

Comment: Please take into consideration that a phone number with all 10 digits equal might actually exist - they would be called gold or platinum numbers, and are sold for very good amounts of money, usually (sometimes?) reserved for very clearly defined people.

Comment: What is `[s-]?` for? Do you want to really allow the `s` letter between numbers?

Comment: How come `489-395-888` is valid if it does not contain 10 digits? Do you realize `(([0-9]{3}))|[0-9]{3})` = `[0-9]{3}` and `[\0-9]` is not `[0-9]` (`/[\0-9]/.test('!')` => `true`)? Well, if the last number group can be 3 or  4 digits, try `var emailformat = /^(?!(\d)(?:\D*\1)*$)\d{3}([\s-]?)\d{3}\2\d{3,4}$/`. (Do not modify this var emailformat declaration if you decide to try it out, do not add any quotes)

Comment: Sorry it’s a typo error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flag a 10 digit phone number, all of whose digits are the same, the easiest thing to do might be to just match for that, and then assert the match is not true:

```
^(\d)\1{2}-\1{3}-\1{4}$
```

### Demo

Comment: I am using in Angular